# Ajax post не работает

Tags: post, ajax

Собственно, почему то не работает post запрос. Библиотека jquery подключена. В ответ приходит только "-";

Вот js код

```
var result = document.getElementById('result');
var title = $("#title").val();
    var text_area = $("#text_area").val();
                $.post('http://site.com/script/post.php', {
            'title':title,
            'text_area':text_area
            }, function (data){
                result.innerHTML = data;
        });
```

Вот php

```
<?php

if (!empty($_POST['title'])) $title= $_POST['title'];  
if (!empty($_POST['text_area'])) $text_area   = $_POST['text_area']; 
echo $text_area.'-'.$title;

?>
```

Comment: >> result.innerHTML = data;

где у вас result берется?

Comment: `var_dump($_POST, $_REQUEST);` сделайте и посмотрите, что вернется.

Comment: Спасибо за внимание оказанное моей проблеме, ошибку нашёл, она наиглупейшая. В скрипте обработчике был конфиг и в нём сокращатель ссылок, он то и мешал.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JS

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://site.com/script/post.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {'title':$("#title").val(), 'text_area':$("#text_area").val() },
    complete: function() {},
    statusCode: {
        200: function(message) {
            alert(message);
        },
        403: function(jqXHR) {
            var error = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText);
            $("body").prepend(error.message);
    }
});
```

Попробуй так.

Comment: Эх... Всё так же, приходит "-"

Answer (score 1):

Если этот код не заработает, значит вы что-то делаете не так.

P.S. Если пользуетесь Хромом, смотрите в консоль что уходит на сервер и что приходит с сервера. У нас нет вашего полного кода. Возможно ошибка не в этом участке кода. Полтергейсты часто в программировании бывают.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="title" />
<textarea id="text_area"></textarea>
```

**JS**

```
var result = $('#result');
var title = $("#title").val();
var text_area = $("#text_area").val();

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://site.com/script/post.php',
    data: 'title=' + title + '&text_area=' + text_area,
    cache: false,
    success: function(response) {
        if (response) {
            result.html(response)
        }
    },

    error:function(xhr, status, errorThrown) { 
         alert(errorThrown+'\n'+status+'\n'+xhr.statusText); 
    }        
});
```

Comment: Не робит. Хотя  данные уходят на сервер.

Comment: попробуйте серверный код post.php написать так:

>>echo $_POST['text_area'].'-'.$_POST['title'];

Comment: Сделал. Такая же хрень, подумал и решил "хватит париться используй -XMLHttpRequest"

Comment: возможно у вас как-то сервер криво настроен... но я даже не представляю что это может быть